# How to make an excel external connection via python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, win32com

How can I make an external connection to a csv file using the win32com library. I have a csv file with massive amount of data and want to create a pivot table out of it. The only issue is that the file is too large and if I try to open it in excel, it doesn't load the entire data, so my pivot table doesn't contain the whole data. In excel we can do an external connection to the csv file and query the data but I'm not sure how to do so programmatically.

Any help/hint will be greatly appreciated